# Somewhat newb question about assy and the heap

Tags: memory-management, assembly

Ultimately I am just trying to figure out how to dynamically allocate heap memory from within assembly.

If I call Linux sbrk() from assembly code, can I use the address returned as I would use an address of a statically (ie in the .data section of my program listing) declared chunk of memory?

I know Linux uses the hardware MMU if present, so I am not sure if what sbrk returns is a 'raw' pointer to real RAM, or is it a cooked pointer to RAM that may be modified by Linux's VM system?

I read this: [How are sbrk/brk implemented in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997425/how-are-sbrk-brk-implemented-in-linux). I suspect I can not use the return value from sbrk() without worry: the MMU fault on access-non-allocated-address must cause the VM to alter the real location in RAM being addressed. Thus assy, not linked against libc or what-have-you, would not know the address has changed.

Does this make sense, or am I out to lunch?

Comment: Is there still a true sbrk syscall? I thought it had been deprecated (in favour of mmap) ages ago. E.g. FreeBSD doesn't have one anymore. Could be that the linux flavour is x86 specific.

Comment: x86 Linux (OpenSuSE 11.3) still has a man page for sbrk(2) & brk(2). But it does say this: "CONFORMING TO 4.3BSD; SUSv1, marked LEGACY in SUSv2, removed in POSIX.1-2001." So not sure. I only started considering calling something lower level than malloc() yesterday, if I find sbrk/brk is not used I'll try to post back here.

Comment: Hmm, it also says: Avoid  using  brk()  and sbrk(): the malloc(3) memory allocation package is the portable and comfortable way of allocating memory. Various systems use various types for the argument of sbrk().  Common are int, ssize_t, ptrdiff_t, intptr_t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unix user processes live in [**virtual memory**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), no matter if written in assembler of Fortran, and should not care about physical addresses. That's kernel's business - kernel sets up and manages the MMU. You don't have to worry about it. [Page faults](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault) are handled automatically and transparently.

[`sbrk(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/brk.2.html) returns a *virtual address* specific to the process, if that's what you were asking.